# Calling C# application form unmanaged C application

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

I have an old C++ application, which is called by some other MFC and WPF applications.
This application expose its functions using `MIDL_INTERFACE` like:

```
// in header file:
MIDL_INTERFACE("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
IDispatch : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT Connect(long hwnd);
    //...
}

MIDL_INTERFACE("D949F6BF-B8D5-4A3F-A7A7-83E9CBCE88DE")
App : public IDispatch 
{
public:
    HRESULT __stdcall Connect(long hwnd);
    //...
}
```

And the app has implementation like:

```
// in .cpp file:
extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)  { /*...*/ }

STDMETHODIMP App::Connect(long hwnd) { /*...*/ }
```

Without messing with the old C++ code that nobody understand, I would like to re-write this application using C#.
Currently, I can easily calling my re-written C# application in other WPF applications, just add a reference to my .exe file.

I know I could build a separate dll by registering COM interop in VisualStudio (like [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12579/Building-COM-Servers-in-NET)). But how can I  let other MFC application to reference my new .exe, without additional COM dll?

Comment: So you what to call a C# exe from MFC applications? You can always use the exe's command line to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose the C# classes (in your new exe) as COM objects, and then you will be able to call them from C++/MFC. More details are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/example-com-class.